# SpringBoot different auths (MS AD & JWT) to one Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I tried to implement small API Gateway for my Mobile App on Spring Boot.

In my architecture i uses MS Active Directory Server for auth staff of company and in future will sms verify code for clients company for sending JWT.

I'm not use layer DAO, UsersRepository and DB connect.

All HTTP requests sending via RestTemplate from Services layer to our inthernal CRM-system.

I implements LDAP AD auth is very simple HttpBasic configuration bellow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/send/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new
                ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("mydomain.com", "ldap://192.168.0.100:389/");

        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})(memberOf=CN=mobileaccess,OU=User Groups,OU=DomainAccountsUsers,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM))");
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.eraseCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

I have two RestController V1 and V2 for example:

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
//get token for staff (AD user) HttpBasic auth
@PostMapping("auth/get/stafftoken")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getToken() {
    // some code...
        HttpHeaders tokenHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        tokenHeaders.setBearerAuth(tokenAuthenticationService.getToken());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(tokenHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

//get JWT if code from sms == code in my CRM-system (for client) not auth - permitAll
@PostMapping("send/clienttoken")
    public @ResponseStatus
    ResponseEntity<?> sendVerifyCode(@RequestParam("verifycode") String verifycode) {
    // some code...
        HttpHeaders tokenHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        tokenHeaders.setBearerAuth(tokenAuthenticationService.getToken());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(tokenHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@RequestMapping("api/v2")
@GetMapping("get/contract/{number:[0-9]{6}")
    public Contract getContract(@PathVariable String number) {
        return contractsService.getContract(number);
    }
```

How to implements Bearer Auth requests to Controller APIv2 with JWT tokens (clients and staff)?

I think this is implemented through filter chain?

Answer (score 0):

So guys

If you implements multi authentification as in my example, first of all create utility class for builds token and validation users JWT. This is standard code, for example:

```
public static String createUserToken(Authentication authentication) {
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authentication.getName())
            .claim(authentication.getAuthorities())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SIGN_KEY)
            .compact();
```

}

```
public static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = extractJwt(request);
    try {
            if (token != null) {
                Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SIGN_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                String username = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SIGN_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
                return username != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, "", Collections.EMPTY_LIST) : null;
            }
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {

        }
    return null;
}
```

Аfter you should create two filters:

1. LoginAuthentificationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter
2. JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean

Code example below

```
public class LoginAuthentificationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
public LoginAuthentificationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(authenticationManager);
}
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain);
}
```

}

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
private RequestMatcher requestMatcher;
public JwtAuthenticationFilter(String path) {
    this.requestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(path);
}
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!requiresAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        return;
    }
    Authentication authentication = JwtUtils.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
private boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return requestMatcher.matches(request);
}
```

}

And at the end
Settings WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/noauth_endpoints").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
           .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(jwtFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilter(loginFilter());
    http.headers().cacheControl();
}
```

Beans

```
@Bean
public LoginAuthentificationFilter loginFilter() {
    return new LoginAuthentificationFilter(authenticationManager());
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter("/api/v2/**");
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("bzaimy.com", "ldap://192.168.0.100:389/");
    provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})(memberOf=CN=mobileaccess,OU=User Groups,OU=DomainAccountsUsers,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM))");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    return provider;
}
```